# Jquery Mobile Grid style incorrect

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have the following grid:

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">

    <!-- header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Main</h1>
        <a href="#optionsPanel" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='/'>Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <!-- content -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="ui-grid-d" id="grdAssignmentDump">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" class="ui-bar">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

</div>
```

For some reason I cannot get the style of the grid to have the "squared" look.  It shows every item as a button and round. I would like to have the grid be squares and connected like it usually is.  Not sure what the problem is.  Here is the javascript to populate the grid.  Everything is working fine, its just the style does not show the correct "squared" style for jquery mobile.  Here is the javascript to fill the grid (working correctly):

```
function LoadInfo(info) {

        // Set Assignment Date
        var e = document.getElementById(info);
        var assignmentDate = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("getAssignmentDump")',
            data: { assignmentId: assignmentId, assignmentDate: assignmentDate },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                // Create assignment dump grid
                var grdHtml = "";

                // Loop through each record returned from json
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                    // Add row to grid
                    grdHtml += "<div class='ui-block-a'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a'>" + item.user + "</div></div>";
                    grdHtml += "<div class='ui-block-b'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a'>" + item.assignmentTime + "</div></div>";
                    grdHtml += "<div class='ui-block-c'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a'>" + item.complete + "</div></div>";
                    grdHtml += "<div class='ui-block-d'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a'>" + item.redone + "</div></div>";

                });

                // Fill grid
                $('#grdAssignmentDump').html(grdHtml);

                // Refresh grid to enhance its styling
                //$('#grdAssignmentDump').grid("refresh");

            },
            error: function (ex) {
                var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is how the columns looks (incorrect):

[image]

Here is how it the columns should look (squared corners):

[image]

What am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: post your css code and also response json object..

Comment: You are putting the response data inside the `ui-bar` , which is acting as *header* of the block. So, inside the `ui-block` below this *header* there will be anything.